# Symbol lookup error after successfully built graph tensorflow tool

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build summerize_graph which is a tensorflow tool used to visualize the graph of model. I build this tool using bazel - referred [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms)

```
$ bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```

when I am trying to use it with this command

```
$ ./summarize_graph --in_graph=20170512-110547.pb
```

is giving this error

> ./summarize_graph: symbol lookup error: /home/sneha/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sneha/5493eb67fb8c3272a4d7ed9f724aa3c2/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/../../../_solib_k8/_U_S_Stensorflow_Stools_Sgraph_Utransforms_Csummarize_Ugraph___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow19IsGoogleCudaEnabledEv

So I am not getting whether I should install cuda or what ? Please help !! Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think it should be a CUDA installation problem, [that function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/util/port.h) just [tells whether it is a GPU build or not](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/core/util/port.cc). Not sure what could be the cause of the error though...

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, okay. Thank you for information :)